# Format decimal number with thousand separator with a dot (.)

Tags: apex, visualforce, decimal, number

I would like to format a visualforce variable `'{!TotalE}'` with a thousand separator as . notation for example

> 123386258.00 becomes 123.386.258

I have tried examples of 
`outputtext 'value="{0, number, #,###,###,##0}"`' this returns 123,386,258 what i would like to achieve is 123.386.258 like a swedish format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `apex:outputField`, it would do the formatting for you based on your locale.

Unfortunately its not possible with `apex:outputText` and `apex:param`. Here is a [similar idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Bqq9).

There was a comment in the idea which could be helpful but would need bit of modification as per requirement:

> Option 1: Standard

```
<apex:outputText value="{0, number, ###,##0.00}">
    <apex:param value="{!Opportunity.Amount}"/>
</apex:outputText> </span>
```

> result : 100,000.00

---

> Option 2: Custom formulas

```
<span>
    {!IF(Opportunity.Amount < 0, 
        "-", 
        "") & 
        IF(ABS(Opportunity.Amount) >= 1000000, 
            TEXT(FLOOR(ABS(Opportunity.Amount) / 1000000)) & ".", 
            "") & 
        IF(ABS(Opportunity.Amount) >= 1000, 
            RIGHT(TEXT(FLOOR(ABS(Opportunity.Amount) / 1000)), 3) & ".", 
            "") & 
        RIGHT(TEXT(FLOOR(ABS(Opportunity.Amount))), 3) & "," & 
        IF(MOD(ABS(Opportunity.Amount) , 1) * 100 < 10, 
            "0" & TEXT(ROUND(MOD(ABS(Opportunity.Amount), 1), 2) * 100), 
            TEXT(MIN(ROUND(MOD(ABS(Opportunity.Amount) , 1), 2) * 100, 99))
        )}
</span>
```

> Result: 100.000,00