# Formatting currencies in different locales (DE, EN, ES, FR & PT) in quote

Tags: apex, visualforce, locale, outputtext, format

My company is dealing with customers all around the world. We use 5 languages (English being the main): DE, EN, ES, FR & PT.
We wanted to send the quotes with localized amounts to our customers who could be English, Spanish, French....speaking.
This means tha the amount should be displayed as follows:
DE: 1.234.567,57 €
EN: €1,234,567.57
ES: 1.234.567,57 €
FR: 1 234 567,57 €
PT: 1.234.567,57 €
I was trying to find a way to format the amounts in the target locale without success. What I did so far is:
1. I am using outputText and passing the format as a parameter.

```
<apex:outputText value="{!currencyFormat}" ><apex:param value="{!currentQLI.UnitPrice}"/></apex:outputText>
```

2.The format is built via an APEX function depending on a custom field on the opportunity

```
/*
 * builds a dynamic currency format
 */
private void setCurrencyFormat() {
    currencyFormat = '{0,number,€ #,##0.00}';
    switch on this.lge {
        when 'ES', 'PT', 'DE' {
            currencyFormat = '{0,number,#.##0,00 €}';
        }
        when 'FR' {
            currencyFormat = '{0,number,# ##0,00 €}';
        }
    }
}
```

This is not working properly as all the formats having comma (,) as a decimal separator are generaing the error:

```
The number format pattern for <apex:outputText> is invalid..
```

Is there any way to make this work properly?

Best Regards

Comment: do you get the error when testing with a user whose locale is ES, PT, DE, or FR?

Comment: Yes, I tried that just now with FR locale and I am getting the same error.
Further more. I created a simple page to be able to easily test the format using the following code block.  I get the same error in the problems tab:

<apex:outputText value="{0,number,€ #.##0,00}">
    <apex:param value="{!Account.AnnualRevenue}" />
</apex:outputText>

Comment: see [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21384/format-decimal-in-apexoutputtext-respecting-the-users-locale) and [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/170079/format-decimal-number-with-thousand-separator-with-a-dot) and [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000Bqq9AAC)

Comment: Thank you for the eedback.  
I already implemented my own formatting function, but I was looking for a more elegant solution.
In Java it is possible to easily do that without reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Cool.  Would you be so kind as to answer your own question as a service to the community